# Fragment com recyclerview fechando aplicação

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Vamos la preciso fazer um `fragment` onde virá informações de pouco a pouco, estou utilizando o método de `RecyclerView` para desenvolver isto. A ideia toda é pegar comentários de certo item.

Primeiramente eu criei um `fragment`, e ficou assim:

```
public class ComentariosFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private List<Comentarios> mList;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_comentarios, container,false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstComentarios);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            ComentarioAdapter adapter = (ComentarioAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter();

            if(mList.size() == llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1){
                List<Comentarios> listAux = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSetComentariosList(10);

                for (int i = 0; i < listAux.size(); i++){
                    adapter.addItemList(listAux.get(i), mList.size());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);


    mList = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSetComentariosList(10);
    ComentarioAdapter adapter = new ComentarioAdapter(getActivity(), mList);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
 }
}
```

Depois disto criei meu `adapter` que ficou assim:

```
public class ComentarioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComentarioAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Comentarios> mList;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;


public ComentarioAdapter(Context c, List<Comentarios> l){
    mList = l;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItemList(Comentarios c,int positon) {
    mList.add(c);
    notifyItemInserted(positon);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_comentario, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder mVH = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return mVH;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nmCliente.setText( mList.get(position).getNmCliente() );
    holder.observacaoAvaliacao.setText( mList.get(position).getObservacaoAvaliacao() );
    holder.ratingBar.setRating( mList.get(position).getAvaliacao() );
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView nmCliente,observacaoAvaliacao;
    public RatingBar ratingBar;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nmCliente = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nmCliente);
        observacaoAvaliacao = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.observacaoAvaliacao);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    }
 }
}
```

Depois criei meu layout com activity assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lstComentarios"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

E meu `item comentario`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:id="@+id/nmCliente"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nmCliente"
    android:layout_below="@+id/observacaoAvaliacao"
    android:max="5"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#A79896"
    android:progressTint="@color/accent_color" />


<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/ampm_text_color"
    android:id="@+id/observacaoAvaliacao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<View
android:id="@+id/vw_divider"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/observacaoAvaliacao"
android:background="@color/pink"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0.8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No meu `MainActivity` estou criando uma lista apenas para testar, faço assim:

```
public List<Comentarios> getSetComentariosList(int qtd){
    String[] nome = new String[]{"Gallardo", "Vyron", "Corvette", "Pagani Zonda", "Porsche 911 Carrera", "BMW 720i", "DB77", "Mustang", "Camaro", "CT6"};
    String[] comentarios = new String[]{"asdasdfsdfasdfasdfasdfasdf", "asdfsdfgfghdfghdfghfd", "Corfsdsdsd s  asdfasf asdvette", "fasdf asdf efaefawefasdf Zonda", "dfsdfsdfsad sdfa df 911 Carrera", "BMWasd weqweqweqwe  720i", "DB7 wqefwefqw e  qwefq we7", "Musta qwerqwer q wqerq ng", "Camar qerqw erq o", "CTqwer qwe wqe6"};
    Integer[] rating = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,3,2,5,2,5,3};
    List<Comentarios> listAux = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < qtd; i++){
        Comentarios c = new Comentarios(rating[i % rating.length], nome[i % nome.length], comentarios[ i % comentarios.length ] );
        listAux.add(c);
    }
    return(listAux);
}
```

Estou chamando todo este processo de outra `fragment`, ou seja quero sair de uma para ir para outra, onde estou fazendo assim:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.favoritar){
        if (!restaurante.isFavorito()) {
            // Adiciona aos favoritos
            adicionarAosFavoritos();
        } else {
            // Remove
            removerDosFavoritos();
        }
    }else if(id == R.id.comentar) {
        FragmentCardapio fgtComentarios = new FragmentCardapio();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_drawer, fgtComentarios).commit();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Quando efetuo o evento do click do botão ele cai em dois `metodos` deste meu `fragment`, o primeiro este:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_favoritar_restaurante, menu);
    menuItemCoracao = menu.getItem(1);

    if (restaurante.isFavorito()) {
        // Altera o icone para favoritado
        menuItemCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favoritado);
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

e logo depois este:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateCarrinho();

    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbarTitle.setText(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante());
}
```

Quando comento um ele cai em outro, quando comento os dois, ele não aparece minha `fragment` com os comentários.

A função `updatecarrinho()` é esta:

```
    private void updateCarrinho() {

    if(txtItensCarrinho != null){
        if (Globales.getPedido() != null && Globales.getPedido().getItens() != null) {
            if (Globales.getPedido().getItens().size() == 1) {
                txtItensCarrinho.setText(Globales.getPedido().getItens().size()
                        + " item no carrinho.");
            } else if (Globales.getPedido().getItens().size() == 0) {
                txtItensCarrinho.setText("Nenhum item no carrinho.");
            } else {
                txtItensCarrinho.setText(Globales.getPedido().getItens().size()
                        + " itens no carrinho.");
            }
        }
        imgCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Globales.getPedido() == null
                        || Globales.getPedido().getItens() == null
                        || Globales.getPedido().getItens().isEmpty()) {
                    MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(),
                            R.string.carrinho_vazio);
                    return;
                }
                Intent intentCarrinho = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.CarrinhoActivity_.class);
                startActivity(intentCarrinho);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

e ela está dando erro na variável `txtItensCarrinho` tentei fazer um `if` para verificar se ela esta `null`, porém nada adiantou. Ja no método `onCreateOptionsMenu` ele da erro na variável `restaurante.isFavorito()`.

No Logcat esta aparecendo o seguinte erro:

> Process: com.projeto.teste, PID: 3304 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.projeto.teste.entity.Restaurante.isFavorito()' on a null object reference

Para ilustrar, isto esta ocorrendo ao clicar neste botão marcado na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale salientar que obotão do lado o coração não esta enviando para nenhuma `view` nem fragment, apenas efetua uma função na página.

Este é o código completo da página que esta chamando meu fragment:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_lista_cardapio)
public class FragmentCardapio extends Fragment {

public static String RESTAURANTE_CARDAPIO = "restaurante_carregado";

@ViewById
StickyListHeadersListView lstCardapio;

@ViewById
TextView txtItensCarrinho;

@ViewById
ImageButton imgCart;

Restaurante restaurante;

CardapioAdapter adapter;
List<Restaurante> cardapio;

MenuItem menuItemCoracao;

@Click(R.id.lytCarrinho)
public void carrinho() {
    if (Globales.getPedido() == null
            || Globales.getPedido().getItens() == null
            || Globales.getPedido().getItens().isEmpty()) {
        MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), R.string.carrinho_vazio);
        return;
    }

    Intent intentCarrinho = new Intent(getActivity(),
            com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.CarrinhoActivity_.class);
    startActivity(intentCarrinho);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@AfterViews
public void init() {
    Globales.setPedido(new Pedido());

    restaurante = (Restaurante) getArguments().getSerializable(
            RESTAURANTE_CARDAPIO);
    Globales.setRestauranteAtual(restaurante);
    carregarCardapio(restaurante);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateCarrinho();

    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbarTitle.setText(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante());
}

public void carregarCardapio(Restaurante restaurante) {
    try {
        final AsyncHttpClient request = new AsyncHttpClient();
        request.setTimeout(60);
        // Parametros
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("cdRestaurante",
                String.valueOf(restaurante.getCodigoRestaurante()));
        params.put("cdCliente", PreferencesUtils.getString(getActivity(),
                PreferencesUtils.PREFERENCIA_CODIGO_CLIENTE));

        // Exibe a mensagem de progresso
        final ProgressDialog progress = MessageUtil.showProgress(
                getActivity(), R.string.aguarde, ResourceUtil.getString(
                        R.string.carregando_cardapio,
                        restaurante.getNomeRestaurante()), true);
        final Context mContext = getActivity();
        progress.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                request.cancelRequests(mContext, true);
            }
        });
        progress.show();

        request.post(Constantes.URL_CARDAPIO, params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String resposta) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        sucessoResposta(resposta);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), R.string.erro_desconhecido);
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), R.string.erro_desconhecido);
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
    }
}

private void sucessoResposta(String json) {
    try {
        Cardapio cardapio = JSONParser.parseCardapio(json);
        Globales.setCardapio(cardapio);
        Globales.getRestauranteAtual().setPagamentos(
                cardapio.getFormasPagamento());
        adapter = new CardapioAdapter(getActivity(), cardapio);
        lstCardapio.setAdapter(adapter);
        final Context context = getActivity();

        lstCardapio.getWrappedList().setOnItemClickListener(
                new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (Globales.getRestauranteAtual().getStatus() == Constantes.STATUS_FECHADO) {
                            MessageUtil.showError(context,
                                    R.string.restaurante_fechado_cardapio);
                            return;
                        }

                        Comida comida = (Comida) adapter.getItem(position);

                        if(comida.isIndisponivel()){
                            MessageUtil.showError(context, "O item selecionado nao está disponível no momento.");
                            return;
                        }

                        Globales.getPedido().setCodRestaurante(restaurante.getCodigoRestaurante());
                        Intent itensActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.AdicionarItemActivity_.class);
                        itensActivity.putExtra(AdicionarItemActivity.COMIDA, comida);
                        itensActivity.putExtra(AdicionarItemActivity.RESTAURANTE,restaurante);
                        startActivityForResult(itensActivity, 0);
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
        try {
            MessageUtil
                    .showError(getActivity(), R.string.erro_desconhecido);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
        }
    }
}

private void updateCarrinho() {

    if(txtItensCarrinho != null){
        if (Globales.getPedido() != null && Globales.getPedido().getItens() != null) {
            if (Globales.getPedido().getItens().size() == 1) {
                txtItensCarrinho.setText(Globales.getPedido().getItens().size()
                        + " item no carrinho.");
            } else if (Globales.getPedido().getItens().size() == 0) {
                txtItensCarrinho.setText("Nenhum item no carrinho.");
            } else {
                txtItensCarrinho.setText(Globales.getPedido().getItens().size()
                        + " itens no carrinho.");
            }
        }
        imgCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Globales.getPedido() == null
                        || Globales.getPedido().getItens() == null
                        || Globales.getPedido().getItens().isEmpty()) {
                    MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(),
                            R.string.carrinho_vazio);
                    return;
                }
                Intent intentCarrinho = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        com.fomedemais.FomeDemais.CarrinhoActivity_.class);
                startActivity(intentCarrinho);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_favoritar_restaurante, menu);
    menuItemCoracao = menu.getItem(1);

    if (restaurante.isFavorito()) {
        // Altera o icone para favoritado
        menuItemCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favoritado);
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.favoritar){
        if (!restaurante.isFavorito()) {
            // Adiciona aos favoritos
            adicionarAosFavoritos();
        } else {
            // Remove
            removerDosFavoritos();
        }
    }else if(id == R.id.comentar) {
        FragmentCardapio fgtComentarios = new FragmentCardapio();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_drawer, fgtComentarios).commit();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void removerDosFavoritos() {
    try {
        final AsyncHttpClient request = new AsyncHttpClient();

        // Parametros
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("cdRestaurante",
                String.valueOf(restaurante.getCodigoRestaurante()));
        params.put("cdCliente", PreferencesUtils.getString(getActivity(),
                PreferencesUtils.PREFERENCIA_CODIGO_CLIENTE));

        request.post(Constantes.URL_EXCLUIR_RESTAURANTE_FAVORITO, params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String resposta) {
                        restauranteRemovido(resposta);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
    }
}

private void adicionarAosFavoritos() {
    try {
        final AsyncHttpClient request = new AsyncHttpClient();

        // Parametros
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("cdRestaurante",
                String.valueOf(restaurante.getCodigoRestaurante()));
        params.put("cdCliente", PreferencesUtils.getString(getActivity(),
                PreferencesUtils.PREFERENCIA_CODIGO_CLIENTE));

        request.post(Constantes.URL_INSERIR_RESTAURANTE_FAVORITOS, params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String resposta) {
                        restauranteFavoritado(resposta);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
    }
}

public void restauranteRemovido(String resposta) {
    try {
        RetornoGenerico retorno = JSONParser.parseGenerico(resposta);
        if (retorno.isSucesso()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    R.string.restaurante_removido_favorito,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Altera o icone para favoritado
        menuItemCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favoritar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
    }
}

public void restauranteFavoritado(String resposta) {
    try {
        RetornoGenerico retorno = JSONParser.parseGenerico(resposta);
        if (retorno.isSucesso()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    R.string.restaurante_adicionado_como_favorito,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Altera o icone para favoritado
        menuItemCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favoritado);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
    }
 }

}

class CardapioHolder {
    TextView txtNomeRestaurante;
    ImageView imgLogoRestaurante;
    TextView txtFuncionamento;
}
```

Comment: Pelo erro, seu objeto restaurante ainda não foi inicializado quando você tentou chamar o método isFavorito()

Comment: Que posso fazer para testar e resolver, pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Foi só um chute meu pois você não postou o código completo, então não dá pra saber onde você tenta inicializar o objeto.

Comment: qual codigo vc quer que eu postei, tentei postar o mais completo possivel

Comment: Onde você declara esse objeto e onde você inicializa ele pela primeira vez?

Comment: coloquei o codigo completo

Comment: @MárcioOliveira viu algo?

Comment: Vi que você está usando essas libraries de injeção de view (prá substituir os tradicionais findViewById). Eu particularmente não gosto, visto que não dá pra saber exatamente em que momento do ciclo de vida da Activity/Fragment eles irão rodar. Por exemplo, você inicializa o objeto restaurante dentro desse @AfterViews, então meu chute é que ele só está rodando depois do onCreateOptionsMenu, por isso o erro. Tenta inicializar o método init() dentro do onCreateView prá ver o que acontece, pois ele roda antes do onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: Como fazer isto ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59012/discussion-between-renan-rodrigues-and-marcio-oliveira).

Comment: Cara, agora estou enrolado no trabalho, mais tarde podemos tentar.

Comment: Ok pode ser então, mais nao mudou nada na alteração

Comment: algum retorno @MárcioOliveira

Comment: Dia tenso hoje. Posta como ficou o código com a alteração que eu falei.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira nem lembro mais kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Renan, fiquei um pouco confuso com a código mas acho que entendi.
Primeira coisa remova do onResume

```
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
        R.id.toolbar_title);
```

E coloco no OnCreate da su Fragment:

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView toolbarTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.toolbar);
    }

}
```

Aconselho vc dar uma lida no http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ para capturar seus objetos e no https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
para controlar melhor os eventos entre fragments e activities.

Abs!